# Como 'combinar' 2 objetos del mismo tipo de una lista?

Tags: java, apex

Estoy trabajando con un framework similar a Java.

Lo que necesito es que 2 objetos del mismo tipo se 'Junten' en uno solo.

por ejemplo

```
List<Opportunity> lista1 = {nombre='Lucas', edad=20};
List<Opportunity> lista2 = {peso=80, altura= 180};
```

Si yo hago:

```
lista1.add(lista2);
```

lista1 va a retornar

```
(opportunity:{nombre=Lucas,edad=20},opportunity:{peso=80, altura=180})
```

lo que yo necesito es que lista1 retorne:

```
(opportunity:{nombre=Lucas,edad=20, peso=80, altura=180})
```

Espero haber sido claro.

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres es poner todas las propiedades en un mismo miembro?

Comment: Exacto, eso es lo que quiero